# How to submit a form without uploading image?

Tags: php

I have a problem with submitting my form if i DON'T upload pictures.
I have a code that uploads picture onto form and puts that picture in my images folder, and later I use that image path to show image in PDF.

```
if (isset($_FILES['img'])){

    $uploaddir = '../images/';
    $img1 = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {
        // move the file to the desired place
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $img1)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!";
        }
    }
}
```

Later I set my variable `$img = $img1` and it outputs the uploaded picture in PDF.

```
$pdf->Image($img,10,70,90);
```

However, If dont upload picture, I get error:

> "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Unsupported
>   image type"

I'm using FPDF for creating PDF file.
Thanks in advance for help. P.S. If you think I can do something better with the code, I'm open to suggestions, i'm only a begginer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, from global variable $_FILES you can get file details:

- name
- type
- tmp_name
- error
- size

In your case you can use:

```
// Check file size is greater than 0
if ($_FILES['size'] > 0 && !empty($_FILES['name'])) {
   // here process FPDF to create PDF file
   // then show successful message
   // any other validation can include in this block
}
else 
{
   // Show error message on your website
}
```

but you can also check file type for more secure and error free technique

Comment: Ok, got the first part, but what if I wanted to just convert form to PDF without picture? If it has picture, show it in PDF, if not, just leave blank space in PDF?

Comment: @grabnem replace img tag to something unknown tag, then create PDF using FPDF, like <img src="image.png" /> to <hi src="image.png" />, hi tag will not be render as image tag and image will be disappeared in PDF

Answer (score 0):

use this To check if the file has been uploaded

```
if (!file_exists($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']))
{
   echo 'No upload';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the upload like this:

```
if($_FILES['img']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) { // No file was uploaded.
    // Do something
}

if($_FILES['img']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { // There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
    // Do something
}
```